# selinux mls ssh getting denied dyntransition - login failure

Tags: linux, redhat, selinux

I am trying to learn SELinux and going though the Red Hat documentation for RHEL 7. I came upon the documentation for Multi Layer Security (MLS) and wanted to try it, so I set SELINUXTYPE=mls and SELINUX=permissive , touched /.autorelabel (echoed an -F into it) and rebooted.

I was able to log in, but wanted to check the audit log to make sure no failure or denials happen that would prevent me from logging in using enforcing mode. I found the following:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1457127380.826:208): avc:  denied  { dyntransition } for      pid=2109 comm="sshd" scontext=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s15:c0.c1023 tcontext=root:sysadm_r:sysadm_t:s0 tclass=process
```

So, I figured that was nothing to worry about (Still learning), so i set SELINUX to enforcing and rebooted. Locked myself out!

I was able to get back in with some hacking and set SELINUX back to permissive, but I am not sure why its not working...

I have tried to restorecon /usr/sbin/sshd and it does have the correct context:

```
ls -Z /usr/sbin/sshd
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:sshd_exec_t:s0 /usr/sbin/sshd
```

But if you look at the tcontect in the error its strange:

```
 tcontext=root:sysadm_r:sysadm_t:s0
```

Anyway, as I stated, I am still learning, so any advice would be helpful... Documentation to explain any examples or solutions would be greatly appreciated - "Teach a man to fish..."

Thanks so much!
Joe

Comment: Nobody uses MLS and half your issue is the policies dont really support it. Nobody really uses it enough for it to gain enough attention to its policies. Its an interesting security model based on bell-la-puda, but in production and in reality -- whereever I've used SELinux before its never been considered.

Comment: @MatthewIfe My understanding is that DoD uses it pretty extensively, but MLS is not something that "works out of the box". It needs to be heavily customized for the security needs of the environment. And that generally requires an SELinux expert or two. Being part of an IPA domain is also a good idea, as it helps ease some of the administrative burden.

Comment: Hi Mathew, yeah, I didn't get the feeling that it was widely used when I was trying to search for the issue, but it does look powerful and as Michael pointed out, the DOD and DOE does seem to use it allot so I would like to learn more about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `root` is not allowed to login directly via ssh on an MLS system.

You will need to ssh in as a `staff_t` user and then `sudo` to root.

Comment: Hi Michael, Oh, ok. Let me try that and see what happens. It does make since that root would not be allowed to log in, so making another user and sudoing should work. I will play with that and see how it works out.